# Python3とソケット通信を用いたカメラ画像の転送について

Tags: python, python3, socket

こんばんは、閲覧していただきありがとうございます。
現在、Python3とソケット通信を用いて、Webカメラの画像を送ろうとしています。
ちなみに、使用するパソコンは1台のみです。

ですが、実行途中でエラーが起きてしまい、その原因が分からず、困っています。
ですので、ご指摘いただけないでしょうか?
よろしくお願いいたします。

【サーバー側】

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

soc.connect(("192.168.0.2", 11000))

print("Finish conecct!")

while(1):
    data = soc.recv(921600)

    data = np.fromstring(data,dtype=np.uint8)

    data = np.reshape(data,(160,120,3))

    cv2.imshow("",data);

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k== 13 :
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

【エラー内容】

```
Finish conecct!
server2.py:14: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  data = np.fromstring(data,dtype=np.uint8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server2.py", line 16, in <module>
    data = np.reshape(data,(160,120,3))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in reshape
  File "C:\Users\S.Tayama\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 301, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\S.Tayama\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (160,120,3)
```

【クライアント側】

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(("192.168.0.2", 11000))

print("Waiting for connection")  

s.listen(1)

soc, addr = s.accept()

print(str(addr)+"Finish conecct")  

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):

    flag,img = cam.read()

    img = img.tostring()

    soc.send(img)

    time.sleep(0.5)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k== 13 :
        break

cam.releace()
```

【エラー内容】

```
Waiting for connection
('192.168.0.2', 56568)Finish conecct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client4.py", line 26, in <module>
    soc.send(img)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] 確立された接続がホスト コンピューターのソウトウェアによって中止されました。
```

Comment: どのような形式のデータを受け取っていますか? `data = soc.recv(921600)` の直後に `print(data[0:64])` などと入れてみてください。

Comment: 回答していただき、ありがとうございます。また、返信して頂きありがとうございます。一度、確かめてみたいと思います。

Comment: ほぼ同じソースなので実はご本人かも。[TCPでカメラからの映像を送信(Python)](https://qiita.com/DIODE/items/cb19d0f7d699c19cf4b2), そして関連しそうな記事。[Pythonでネットワーク越しにカメラの映像をストリーミング](https://qiita.com/tokoroten-lab/items/bb27351b393f087650a9), [Python初心者がScikit-imageの例題を自分用に使うためのヒント5　ネットワークアプリに組み込む](https://qiita.com/nonbiri15/items/5fd0c8b789ba9857dbed)